# Combine or merge values

Tags: r, merge, numeric

I would like to combine/merge my values into each other and become one value in R. For instance, to combine  1+3, 5+6, 10+11, 12+13. Does anyone know how to do that? :-)

```
tibble::tibble(
  Educational_level = c(1, 3, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13)
```

This is what I have tried, but it do not merge the factors that I would like when I run the linear regression.

ess7no <- ess7no %>%
mutate(edlvdno = as_factor(edlvdno)) %>%
mutate(edlvdno = recode(edlvdno, "1" = "3" , "5" = "6", "10" = "11", "12" = "13"))

Comment: Hey, could you please show your desired output? I don't really get what you mean by (combine/merge).

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: What I mean by "combine/merge" is being able to put together different values and make it into one value. For example, put together the numeric value = 1 and numeric value = 3 into one value.

Comment: I'm new to rstudio, so I'm sorry for unclear explanations. However, I want to do a linear regression where I need all the numeric levels. The values "contains" similar labels, so therefore, I would like to merge them so it is easier to analize later on.

Comment: Can you include the expected outcome/results in your question

Comment: try `ess7no %>% mutate(Education_level = recode(Education_level, '1'=3, '5'=6, '10' = 11, '12' = 13))`

Comment: I will, thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- tibble(
  Educational_level = c(1, 3, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13),
  Labels = c(
    "Not graduated", "Primary school", "High school", "High school",
    "Bachelor", "Bachelor", "Master", "Master"
  )
)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Labels = ifelse(Labels %in% c(
    "Not graduated",
    "Primary school"
  ), stringr::str_c("Not graduated", "_", "Primary school"), Labels)) %>%
  group_by(Labels) %>%
  summarise(Educational_level = sum(Educational_level))
```

Comment: Thank you, Julian :-) I'm sorry, but I explained my issue wrong. I think I have edited it right now.